# Copying the IP of a tab in SuperPuTTY to the clipboard

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, superputty

I have opened a couple of sessions on [SuperPuTTY](https://code.google.com/p/superputty/). Is there any way to copy the IP of a tab in SuperPuTTY to the clipboard?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SuperPuTTY calls the putty.exe context menu when you right click the tab associated with the session. The functionality you ask for does not exist in the putty application.

Comment: Thanks, yes maybe they could be some option to copy the IP outside the context menu?